# Pronunciation of the symbol $\varnothing$ of the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The symbol $\varnothing$ for the empty set was introduced by Bourbaki, inspired by the Norwegian alphabet $\varnothing.$ It has no relation with the Greek letter $\phi.$

From my schooldays, when the concept of the empty set was introduced, I found people pronouncing this symbol of the empty set as "Phi".

My questions are:

If the symbol has no connection with the Greek letter "Phi", then is it legitimate to call it "Phi"?

If not, what should we call the symbol $\varnothing$?

How is the Norwegian letter $\varnothing$ pronounced?

Comment: The Norwegian letter Ø is not pronounced anywhere near the same as O, it is just that most people cannot pronounce it. I would probably just say empty set, rather than pronounce the notation.

Comment: The pronunciation of the letter 'ø' is somewhat similar to the pronunciation of 'o' in "word" (or 'i' in "bird"), isn't it, @TobiasKildetoft?

Comment: Okay @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: @DanielFischer Somewhat, yes (at least that is probably the closest analogue in English). It can also be pronounced slightly differently in different words.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft But here's the killer question: how does the pronunciation compare to the pronunciation of the Swedish letter 'ö'?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is pretty much the same (and also as the German letter Ö), or at least close (there are probably also subtle differences between how Ø is pronounced in Norwegian and Danish).

Answer (score 16):

I'd read $A=\varnothing$ as *$A$ is empty* or *$A$ is the empty set*.

Answer (score 1):

Ø in Norwegian is pronounced somewhat similar to u in **u**nder or ea in **ea**rly [1].

I think it is generally called "the empty set" and it is not acceptable to call it "phi".

[1] http://www.omniglot.com/writing/norwegian.htm

Comment: Is not it a Greek letter?

Comment: @keramat Similar but not the same as phi: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi

Answer (score 1):

I usually pronounce $\varnothing$ as "null set" in the same way that I pronounce $<$ as "less than." Alternatively, I also read $A=\varnothing$ as "$A$ is null" as well as "$A$ is the null set." I also use empty, but others have mentioned that, and I thought I should add null as an alternative pronunciation. I would call the symbol itself either "null set symbol" much like I would call the symbol $<$ a "less than sign" or (less commonly) "less than symbol."